# Gear Watch Designer Step Count Language Change

Tags: tizen

While adding steps count in gear fit sample if I set Step Counts
text as "Sync to device", language doesn't change as expected. I mean if I select
arabic then "%d steps" should be changed as "%d [arabic of 'steps']" etc.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, as far as I know, functionality you are expecting is currently unavailable up to Gear Watch Designer Version 1.1.1.
Hope this functionality will be added in future release.

Thanks.